# Display data DB to listview with flyoutmenu (xamarin)

Tags: c#, database, listview, xamarin, flyout

I'm programming a personal mobile app in c# xamarin in order to save password (eg : social network / mail / game / online purchase etc...).
I have an issue to display the data in the DB into the listview, it is always blank.
My goal is when I click on a menuitem from a flyoutpage, only the data from the menuitem pushed display on the listview.
the object in the menuitem (category about the password) match with my tables in the DB.

here some pictures to better understand
[The page after the login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gV4u.png)
[flyoutmenuitem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p8YI.png)

I know a flyoutpage has a navigationPage method and it is using to go on a new page, but is it possible to do all my operations in the FlyoutPageDetail or do I need to create new pages and do all my stuff in these new pages ?

When i debug step by step and I click on a category, I'm go to the good method (Listview_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)

here my code about my different pages
DataDisplay C#

```
`public partial class DataDisplay : FlyoutPage
{
   
    public DataDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FlyoutPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;

    }

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedCategory = e.SelectedItem as DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem;
        if (selectedCategory == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        DataBase dbConnexion = new DataBase();
        switch (selectedCategory.Title)
        {
            case "Administratif":
                var getDataAdmin = dbConnexion.GetAdministratifData();
                var result = getDataAdmin.Result;
                GetDataDB getDataDB = new GetDataDB();
                getDataDB.GetDataFromDB = new List<GetDataDB>();
                foreach (var data in result)
                {                        
                    GetDataDB.GetDataFromDB.Add(new GetDataDB { Titre = data.Titre, Login = data.Login, Password = data.Password, Url = data.Url });                        
                }
                                
                break;

            case "Ecommerce":

                break;

            case "Jeux":

                break;

            case "Mail":

                break;

            case "Reseauxsociaux":

                break;
        }
        
        IsPresented = false;
        FlyoutPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }        
}`
```

DataDisplay XAML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MemoDePasse.DataDisplay"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MemoDePasse">
<FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <pages:DataDisplayFlyout x:Name="FlyoutPage" />
</FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:DataDisplayDetail />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
</FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>`
```

DataDisplayDetail C#

```
`public partial class DataDisplayDetail : ContentPage
{

    public DataDisplayDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new GetDataDB();
    }

    public void BtnClickGoAddingDataPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AddingDataPage());
    }
}`
```

DataDisplayDetail XAML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MemoDePasse.DataDisplayDetail"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MemoDePasse"
         x:DataType="local:GetDataDB"
         Title="Catégories">


<StackLayout>
    <ListView 
    x:Name="ListViewData"
    SeparatorVisibility="Default"
    SeparatorColor="Black"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GetDataFromDB}">

        <ListView.Header>
            <Grid 
            BackgroundColor="LightGray"
            IsEnabled="True"
            IsVisible="True">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Titre"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Default"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="Login"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Default"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                <Label
                Grid.Column="2"
                Text="Mot de passe"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Default"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                <Label
                Grid.Column="3"
                Text="URL"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Default"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Titre}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Login}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Url}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="End">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button
        x:Name="Add"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Text="Ajouter"
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        Clicked="BtnClickGoAddingDataPage"/>

        <Button
        x:Name="Update"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Text="Modifier"
        BackgroundColor="BlueViolet"/>

        <Button
        x:Name="Delete"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="Supprimer"
        BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>`
```

DataDisplayFlyout C#

```
`public partial class DataDisplayFlyout : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView;

    public DataDisplayFlyout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new FlyoutPage1FlyoutViewModel();
        ListView = MenuItemsListView;
    }

    class FlyoutPage1FlyoutViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        
        public FlyoutPage1FlyoutViewModel()
        {
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem>(new[]
            {
                new DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem { Id = 0, Title = "Administratif" },
                new DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem { Id = 1, Title = "Ecommerce" },
                new DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem { Id = 2, Title = "Jeux" },
                new DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem { Id = 3, Title = "Mail" },
                new DataDisplayFlyoutMenuItem { Id = 4, Title = "Reseauxsociaux" },
            });
        }            
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}`
```

DataDisplayFlyout XAML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MemoDePasse.DataDisplayFlyout"
         Title="Flyout">
<StackLayout>
<ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
  <ListView.Header>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#03A9F4">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Catégories" Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
  </ListView.Header>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="15"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>`
```

GetDataDB C# (this is the binding source for my listview with the property GetDataFromDB)

```
`public class GetDataDB
{
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public IList<GetDataDB> GetDataFromDB { get; set; }
    public GetDataDB()
    {
        
    }
}`
```

If you want more details, please tell me.

I thank you in advance.
Best Regards.

Comment: Each page is an XAML file.  If you can have an XAML file that can handle both the views, than you only need one page.  If you need two XAML files than you need two pages.

Comment: I deleted all my lines from DataDisplay XAML and just test with a Label with the text Test.
The Label is visible on the page.
I think something is wrong with the ListView but I don't know what :\

Comment: there are many things wrong in your code.  1) most pages do not have a `BindingContext`.  2) why does `GetDataDB` have a recursive `IList<GetDataDB>`?  3) your flyout page builds `GetDataDB` when an item is seleced but it is never used anywhere 4) why does `DataDisplayFlyout` and `DataDisplayDetail` declare a `ListView` in the code behind and the XAML?

Comment: I'd suggest you focus on getting one page with one ListView working first, then add in the complexity of the flyout menu and other pages

Comment: For the IList<GetDataDB> in GetDataDB it is correct, I deleted the second in DataDisplay.
I updated the DataDisplay page (c#) In fact, i never used the property GetDataFromDB in the class GetDataDB.
The ListView was for a previous test to add the object in the itemsource of the ListView (deleted too).
For Binding contect I don't know what to put
BindingContext = this ?

Comment: UPDATE: I did a test with a new page and works like a charm :)
I think there is a problem with the flyoutmenu and the 2 pages FlyoutPage and FlyoutPageDetail.
Well, I think I need to use it by default, that means when I click on a category, a new page open and display the listview.
I thought I can use only the first page name by default PageDetail but I don't think so.

Comment: I think that because each time you select an item in flyout, you create a new instance of  GetDataDB in ```ListView_ItemSelected``` : ```GetDataDB getDataDB = new GetDataDB();```. This new instance is not the BindingContext for ```DataDisplayDetail``` page as you have already set it  in .cs file: ```BindingContext = new GetDataDB();```. Two different instances.

Comment: May I know if this question has been solved?

Comment: Yes, but I did in a different way, I mean when I chose a category, a new page opens with the data displayed in the ListView and I must push the back button in order to chose another category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem but in a different way.

Comment: Please describe your solution